# jQuery onclick multiple elements with the same class

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, click

I have been doing a fair bit of searching for this one, and I think I am on the cusp of the answer, but I am stuck! Basically, I am looking to click one element which will in turn click two other elements of the same class. When I do this, one element is clicked, whereas the other isn't:

```
jQuery('.et-pb-arrow-prev').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('a.et-pb-arrow-prev').click();
    console.log('DONE');
});
```

I am able to switch the elements around so the element not being clicked, is clicked instead of the other, but I can't get both other elements to click. Instead, I am getting this as an error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I think I'm almost there, but I am lost now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: for `max call stack size exceeded` i think you need to share some more of your code because this wont cause this error

Comment: try to write return false; at the end of code inside block i.e. after *jQuery('a.et-pb-arrow-prev').click();* line

Comment: It's jQuery on a Divi Theme of WordPress. Link to site here: https://futures-dev.uts.edu.au/home-new-aiva/

Comment: Could you please give an example of writing return false?

Comment: Could you please supply more information about the markup that you're applying this jQuery to?

Comment: Yes, but can you give me exact use of it? So that I can work in that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you trigger the click, the current element's click handler gets called again that is the reason of call stack error.

```js
jQuery('.et-pb-arrow-prev').on('click', function(e, manual) {
  if (typeof manual === 'undefined' || manual === false) {
    jQuery('a.et-pb-arrow-prev').not(this).trigger('click', true);
    console.log('Triggered', this.textContent.trim());
  } else {
    console.log('DONE', this.textContent.trim());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="et-pb-arrow-prev" href="#">1</a>
<a class="et-pb-arrow-prev" href="#">2</a>
<a class="et-pb-arrow-prev" href="#">3</a>
<a class="et-pb-arrow-prev" href="#">4</a>
```

Comment: That's fixed it! I am a little lost in your explanation, but it fixed it! Thanks a million! If it's not asking too much, could you go over your code for me?

Comment: Any idea why when I put this code in the footer, it doesn't work, but in the console it does?

Comment: @Ollie whether the elements are created dynamically

Comment: @Ollie try `jQuery(document).on('click', function(e, manual) {`

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work? I have a feeling that there is other jQuery overwriting the snippet. I am working with a WordPress theme, and I have zero access to the theme files, so I can't just enqueue the script from `functions.php`. It's being sideloaded from the theme into an index.js

Answer (score 0):

the issue here is that your calling function is put up as an infinite function means  the first click is based on class  **.et-pb-arrow-prev** which will trigger another click event which is also a class **.et-pb-arrow-prev** and hence it will go on

so my advice is to put ids instead of classes for click events

Comment: Thanks, I am getting the same issue. 2 of the 3 elements are clicked, but one is excluded, and I still get the Maximum call stack size exceeded. Thoughts?

Comment: sorry mate i just read ur issue carefully here your isssue is that the function is trapped in an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Its an infinite loop due to which you are getting the mentioned error. Try to use a different name for the element to which you are binding the click event in which you are trying to click two other elements having same class.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xjvqdbog/2/) is the sample jsfiddle, where I have used `.wrapper` class. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'each' where 'this' is each element on the class:

```
$( ".et-pb-arrow-prev" ).each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function(){
        console.log(this, "with index " + index + " is clicked");
    });
});
```